# After running 'npm start' command project is compiling correctly but not creating assets folder with bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working on a new project on react js using lynda "Reactjs essential training". Issue is when i run "npm start" command it compiles my project successfully but neither "assets" directory created nor "bundle.js" created why?

I have used my modified "webpack.config.js" what was different from the training exercise files as the provided file not working for me. Below is the code:

```
.babelrc
--------
{
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/react"]
}

package.json
------------
{
"name": "react-essential",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A project focusing on React and related tools",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
"webpack": "^4.28.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server"
},
"author": "Muhammad Waqas",
"license": "MIT"
}

webpack.config.js
-----------------
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist/assets",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "assets"
},
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: __dirname + "/dist",
    port: 3000
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: ["babel-loader"]
    }]
}
}
```

Whenever i run "npm  start" it should start the webpack-dev-server and changes (if any) should be reflected in the browser.

Comment: Can you also post the not modified file, to be able to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack development server does not write to disk. it serves from memory. if you wish to create a production build, that will get outputted to the assets folder, you need to add a build script, which you will run.

**Add the follow build script to your package.json file, just after the start script, the order does not matter though:**

`"start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
"build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js",`

Then you can **run the following on the command line, to create a build**

`npm run build`

just like running

`npm run start`

Comment: How can you set start up so that it automatically builds everytime

Answer (score 0):

The webpack dev server doesn't write any assets to disk. It serves them all from memory.